# prevent null/empty field submissions error message

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor

I have a form that allows users to enter data into a database. I'm having an issue with the error message displayed by triggering invalid form entries. What happens is if I submit the form with null fields, a red pre-defined error message pops up for about a second, but then the html elements transform into literal text on the page immediately after. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
namespace BillingApp.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class AUTHORIZED_USERS
{

    public int USID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "<br /><font style='color:red;'>Associate name required</font>")]       
    public string FLNAME { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "<br /><font style='color:red;'>SSO ID required</font>")]
    public string UNAME { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "<br /><font style='color:red;'>Security group required</font>")]       
    public string SECURITY_GROUP { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: You should add the css styles for your validation messages to the relevant .css file you load into your page. Don't mix styling with text, plus you are repeating yourself every time you define `<br /><font...`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Could you post at least part of the page where html elements are "literal text" ? As a an image I mean.

Comment: I'm repeating the font styles because there's text on the page underneath each of those fields of which I don't want to have that style applied. Is there no way to handle this within the model? Also there aren't 3 fields, there are 4, 3 are required and the other is the primary key which is autoincrementing and created by sql. Last time I tried posting an image it said I don't have permissions or something of that nature.